# How to express the concept "for each disctinct grouping of column value combinations" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

**English**

I am translating a line of text

> for each disctinct grouping of column value combinations

I came up with

> para cada grupo distinto de combinaciones de valores por columna

but I guess there is a better way to express this concept.

**Spanish**

Estoy traduciendo una linea de texto

> for each disctinct grouping of column value combinations

hasta el momento tengo:

> para cada grupo distinto de combinaciones de valores por columna

supongo que hay una mejor manera de expresar el concepto.

Comment: Podrías agregar la frase completa por favor? Creo que el contexto completo puede hacer más fácil que recibas una mejor respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues, a falta de algún contexto, yo optaría por:

> para cada forma distinta de agrupamiento de parejas de campo y valor

Puedes substituír *forma de agrupamiento* por otro término semejante: *forma de agrupar*, *tipo de agrupamiento*, etc.

En cualquier caso, creo que *no* deberías traducir «column value combinations» como «combinaciones de valor por columna». Creo que el concepto es el de «combinaciones de valores *y* columnas». Pero sin más contexto, no puedo asegurarlo.